# Can I reasonably assume mobile browsers with JavaScript also support jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realise that this question may be almost impossible to answer definitively, but:

Is it *reasonable* to assume that mobile browser with JavaScript can also cope with jQuery? We're talking relatively basic jQuery such as click events and Ajax.

I'm writing a mobile HTML app. It involves slippy maps so anyone who wants to use it has to have JavaScript.

I'd much prefer to use jQuery for the rest of the coding if possible, but can I reasonably say to the client "any phone with JavaScript should support basic jQuery"?

I know about jQuery mobile, but I'm specifically talking about phones that aren't advanced enough to handle jQuery mobile, but do have JavaScript.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

jQuery is not a language. It is a library written in JavaScript, and therefore if you can run JavaScript reasonably well, you should be able to run jQuery without any problems.

With that being said, nothing compares to actual testing. Periodically check that your code works across multiple platforms (not only on different phones, but different web browsers as well).

Comment: There are many versions of Javascript though and not all jQuery's will run on all versions on all browsers.

Comment: @Rudie, that is true, thus why I added "if you can run JavaScript reasonably well" in the original answer :)

Comment: Fair enough @Stargazer712, but my phone (Nokia 6300 LOL) runs pretty decent javascript on Opera Mini, but jQuery is way too much. (I can however fake media queries on it with a small script.) So it all depends on your definition of "reasonably well" ;)

Comment: While pretty much anyone who supports javascript will do so correctly, the DOM is another matter entirely. I have no idea about the level of DOM support throughout the mobile world. Since jQuery wraps the DOM, it will only work to the extent that the underlying DOM does.

Answer (score 1):

javascript is javascript. You can always use `jQuery.support` to [detect features](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.support/). You should test on the browsers you want to support anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple: yes.

JQuery, and especially its most basic features, is designed to be cross browser. If the mobile browser has reasonable javascript support, JQuery should not be an issue.

For fallbacks on features you aren't sure whether or not are supported, you can use `jquery.Support` or [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It should run okay on most... don't expect much from explorer pocket.

> Although jQuery functions across these
>   browsers, IRL many of the cool 
>   effects that jQuery makes simple won't
>   be seen on a mobile browser,  because
>   the interface is so different.  There
>   is (almost) no concept  of mousedown,
>   mouseup, or hover; click and focus
>   behave differently,  screensize is
>   different vs effective window size,
>   animations are slow,  etc.  The
>   challenge in mobile browsers is mostly
>   in the interface  design.  The main
>   advantage IMO is AJAX-loaded content,
>   for speed and  low data/bandwidth
>   usage.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that mobile does not have the same set of events.

Answer (score 1):

In short: yes.

HOWEVER, if you're only doing Ajax and other little things, you'll see a significant speed gain just using vanilla JS.  But I do realize this can be somewhat of a pain.  There are lighter-weight packages out there, like [xui](http://xuijs.com/).

Honestly, I'd consider programming separate sites for mobile Safari (iOS and Android), and other lower-powered devices that don't run WebKit.

To iterate again:  jQuery.mobile is NOT a replacement for jQuery, but rather framework that builds on jQuery, much like jQuery-ui does.  This would be an even larger footprint and bootstrap time.

Answer (score 0):

You can check http://jquerymobile.com/ - maybe it is what you should use on your pages instead of "regular" jquery.

Comment: This is not a replacement for jQuery, it's an addendum.  It's means to pair with it, much like jQuery-ui.

Answer (score 0):

Yes but you will better off using jQuery Mobile in case you are developing for mobile devices. It's optimized for them.

Comment: jQuery Mobile is a UI library that builds on top of jQuery. You don't choose between them.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [jQuery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/), as well as [this very informative slideshare](http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/) which describes the scope and difficulty of the problem you're facing.